# How can I utilize the whole web page with my table

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can I utilize the whole page with my table.  Right now it seems to be centered but I would like to expanded it larger to utilize the whole web page.  I still have 4 inches of margin on each side of my 24 inch monitor. I though table-responsive would handle that when converting to bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="generator-wrapper text-center">
        <h2> Sites </h2>
            <div class="generator-list">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <table id="generator-table">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 0)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Distance (Miles) </th>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 0)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Distance (Feet) </th>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 2)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Name </th>
                                             <th>Address </th>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 4)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Type(s) </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                <tbody id="generator-body">
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>      
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding margins to my css code.

margin-left: -300px;
margin-right: -300px;

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is use `.container-fluid` on the first div. This will help in spanning the entire width of the viewport.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

update:

Your syntax seems to be slightly messed up as well. You shouldn't have a `div` within a table as it will cause you rendering issues. Also looks like you're trying to use the table rows as grid, this isn't advisable as it can also cause weird rendering issues.

```
<table id="generator-table">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wg06xa4L/1/

if you aren't using an editor already i'd recommend using visual studio code as it will highlight a lot of these structure issues for you.

Comment: Thank you for recommending VS Studio Code.  I finally decided to try it and it works great.  Any recommended extensions to use.  I am using Prettier Code Form, HTML tag wrapper , Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 and Highlighter.    I am still unable to Widen my table I will update my code

Comment: @Scott No worries, "Prettier - Code formatter" is a good one for formatting a range of different files. and "HTML Snippets" is a nice time saver.

Comment: jsfiddle  I cut and paste your code into my project and it still wasn't full width. I would like to have it full-width then just add some padding to the right and left margin so that my table is expanded.  Any help is appreciated.